# Why does this function not correctly multiply the values in the array by the given multiple?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to write a function in C that takes a pointer to an array and returns that pointer with all the values multiplied by the multiple. I have:

```
int* returnNpledArray(int *a, int n){
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        *a++ *= n;
    }
    return a;
}
```

but when I call it, which I do in the main this way:

```
    int sample2[] = {-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8};
    returnNpledArray(sample2, 3);

    int d = 0;
    for (d = 0; d < SIZE; d++){
        printf("%d\n", *sample2); 
    }
```

the entire array prints out as only the first value in it multiplied by n. I thought that because in the function, I say *a++ *= n; that I am both dereferencing the value at that spot in a AND incrementing the pointer. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What is this SIZE constant? Could it be 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do following in for loop:

```
for (d = 0; d < SIZE; d++){
    printf("%d\n", *(sample2 + d));
}
```

OR

```
for (d = 0; d < SIZE; d++){
    printf("%d\n", sample2[d]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are stuck at one pointer i.e. `sample` by doing `printf("%d\n", *sample2);`, instead it should be `printf("%d\n", sample2[d]);`

Comment: Fixed. please check again.

Comment: is there a way to print out the values with pointers only, not sample[d]?

Comment: yes. Use `*(sample2+d)`, but remember it means the same thing, just a syntax difference.

Comment: sample[d] is with pointers only, its just a notation difference.  If you really wanted you could do `*(sample + d)` but it means the exact same thing

Answer (score 3):

If you *want* to iterate using pointers only, you can use the following:

```
int *current = sample;
int *end = sample + SIZE;
for ( ; current < end; current ++) {
    printf("%d\n", *current); 
}
```

Notice that we're advancing the `current` pointer here to point to the next `int`; additionally, `end` is a pointer pointing to just past he last element in the `sample` array.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you are just printing the first value

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 10
int* returnNpledArray(int *a, int n){
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        *a++ *= n;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
int sample2[] = {-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8};
returnNpledArray(sample2, 3);

int d = 0;
for (d = 0; d < SIZE; d++){
    printf("%d\n", sample2[d]);
}
}
```

Output

```
-30
-24
-18
-12
-6
0
6
12
18
24
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to write the code would be `a[i] *= n;`. You also neglected to include where `SIZE` is defined, which could be in error.

As it is, the increment should happen, return the pre incremented value,  dereference it, read, modify, write.  The multiply code should work.

Ultimately, it's actually your print function at fault. It isn't iterating over the array.
Try `printf("%d\n", sample2[d]);`

Comment: the size was defined at the top as 10. Is there a way to print but only use pointer notation in the printf call?

Comment: You could use `*(sample2 + d)` but it means exactly the same thing and is handled the same by any sane compiler

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making it complex during multiplication? I think you can do it like this.

```
int* returnNpledArray(int *a, int n){
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        a[i] = a[i]*n;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Here is the main function

```
int sample2[] = {-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8};
returnNpledArray(sample2, 3);

int d = 0;
for (d = 0; d < SIZE; d++){
    printf("%d\n", sample2[d]);
}
```

I am assuming SIZE is the size of array.